# Viewing Commits From All Git Repositories Found Recursively within a Directory

Tags: git, bash

Suppose `dir0` contains multiple subdirectories, many of which contain their own git repositories.

Is there a way for me to see the git commits of **all** of these repositories (perhaps some command to the effect of "show me all of the commits made in any git repository found in `dir0` made in the last 24 hours")?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
find dir0 -name '.git' -printf '%h\n' | while read line; do echo "$line"; cd $line; git log --since="24 hours ago"; cd -; done
```

If your are on OSX, you can install `GNU find` with:

```
brew install findutils
```